# Regarding config.active_record.default_timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have in my **application.rb** :

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

What happens because of this, is that whenever something is saved to the database, it timestamps it to the User's timezone who posted it.

Guessing here.. but if a user is in EST, the timestamp is relative to EST. If they are in PST, the stamp is relative to PST.

Therefore, if they are to pull the hour out, then the database converts it back to the time in which they originally stored it as. This, of course, is happening all under the hood in Rails, and there's no actual record of this conversion.

Say for instance, I save a date for 4pm. I check my database, and it is in UTC. Then if I show that date in a view, its back in my local timezone without me saying so specifically.

Here cometh the question!

Say that I want an object to be cloned by a Resque worker overnight on a server located in Virginia for an object that was originally created by a user living in Ireland.

What will happen, is that object will update to the server's local time and not to the user.

**The Question:** How can I extract the original local time that object was saved in?

Comment: i've never worked with this kind of stuff, but i guess it might be a good idea to always store times in utc and have the users timezone stored separatly, as this should be something for the presentation layer.

Comment: Which, gratefully, I already have. I guess that's my solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you store the user's time zone somewhere and set it on every request, most likely in `application_controller.rb`. Obviously, this step is not performed by the Resque worker, so it will default to the server time zone.

If the object or some variable in the worker is associated with a specific user somehow, you can fetch the user's time zone in the worker method and set it just like in the main application:

```
Time.zone = obj.user.time_zone
```

Or, if appropriate, store the time zone in the object itself.